# Keeping all columns after Pandas groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
         Postcode       Borough          Neighbourhood
283      M8Z     Etobicoke              Mimico NW
284      M8Z     Etobicoke     The Queensway West
285      M8Z     Etobicoke  Royal York South West
286      M8Z     Etobicoke         South of Bloor
287      M9Z  Not assigned           Not assigned
```

I have a Pandas dataframe in this format. I have used the code

```
Toronto =Toronto.groupby('Postcode'['Neighbourhood'].agg([('Neighbourhood', ', '.join)]).reset_index()
```

to group by Postcode such that Neighbourhoods are comma separated for a unique Postcode identifier. How can I modify this code so that the 'Borough' column remains in the dataframe? There's a one-to-one mapping between this and Postcode

Comment: [Don't post pictures of code / data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). We cannot copy and paste your picture. You have your data already in Jupyter Notebook. Simply use `print(Toronto)` and copy&paste the output of that in your question.

Comment: Apologies. Sorted!

Comment: Is there a 1:1 mapping between Postcode and Borough? If so just add it as a grouping column. Otherwise, specify how to aggregate that column in your `agg`

Comment: Yes, there's a one to one mapping. I'm not sure about the syntax to add it as a grouping column. Everything I've tried produces errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with

```
Toronto = (Toronto.groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough'])['Neighbourhood']
                   .agg([('Neighbourhood', ', '.join)]).reset_index())
```

Thanks @ALollz for the nudge

Comment: If you want to clean the syntax up a bit you can do: `Toronto.groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough'], as_index=False).Neighbourhood.agg(', '.join)`. `as_index=False` makes it so there's no need to reset the index, and since you already select the Neighbourhood series you can just specify how to aggregate it

Answer (score 1):

Since the relationship is 1:1, you can use `unique` and you would be fine.

```
df.groupby('Postcode').agg({
    'Neighbourhood': ','.join,
    'Borough': 'unique'
})
```

Output:

```
                                                          Neighbourhood     

            Borough
Postcode                                                                                   
M8Z       Mimico NW,The Queensway West,Royal York South West,South of Bloor     [Etobicoke]
M9Z                                                            Not assigned  [Not assigned]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to add *Borough* to the group-by list:

```
Toronto.groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough']).Neighbourhood\
    .agg(', '.join).reset_index()
```